# how can i change a value which is common in all selected objects in one go?

Tags: rigging, selection-tools

how can i change a value (in my case "space") which is common in all selected objects(in my case bones) in one go.
I have copy rotation on my finger bones and because default space is world space i need to change it to local space. Right now I am doing it individually( each finger have 3 bones so it means 12 times i need to change it which is quite laboring task).

so in short i want to know if it is possible to select all finger bones and change its space to local in one go rather than doing it individually.(copy attribute doesn't work because target objects are different)

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/502168598450798592/747089000988409916/unknown.png
[image: visual clue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as these bones have the same constraint, select them, select *Local* in the contraint *Space* dropdown menu, but don't click on it (!!), instead press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112188/discussion-on-answer-by-moonboots-how-can-i-change-a-value-which-is-common-in-al).